# Cannot compose tweets with Twitter Kit 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios11, twitterkit

I followed instruction from https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/compose-tweets to compose tweets via my Object C app for iOS 11

```
// Objective-C
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];

[composer setText:@"just setting up my Twitter Kit"];
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitterkit"]];

// Called from a UIViewController
[composer showFromViewController:self completion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
    if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
    }
}];
```

However, after clicking Connect button at [Connect your account] screen, it turned back app without composing tweet (Twitter logged in already).
It seems showFromViewController didn't run.
Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I made it run by following this instruction (it's in Japanese but you don't need to understand Japanese to read it, just read the code : ) )
http://iphone-app-developer.seesaa.net/article/452391500.html

Comment: I am having the same problem. Do you have an idea of what exactly caused the problem at the "Connect your account" stage?

Answer (score 0):

First of all get **read/write permission** on Twitter for your app.

```
    if ([[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore hasLoggedInUsers]) {
  NSString *twitterLoggedInInfo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TwitterLoggedInInfo"];

  if (![twitterLoggedInInfo isEqualToString:@"v3"]) {
    NSString *currentUserID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
    [[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore logOutUserID:currentUserID];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"v3" forKey:@"TwitterLoggedInInfo"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
      if (session) {
        TWTRComposerViewController *composer = [[TWTRComposerViewController alloc] initWithInitialText:tweetText image:tweetImage videoURL:nil];
        [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
    }];
  } else {
    if (![twitterLoggedInInfo isEqualToString:@"v3"]) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"v3" forKey:@"TwitterLoggedInInfo"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    TWTRComposerViewController *composer = [[TWTRComposerViewController alloc] initWithInitialText:tweetText image:tweetImage videoURL:nil];
    [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
  } else {
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
      if (session) {
        TWTRComposerViewController *composer = [[TWTRComposerViewController alloc] initWithInitialText:tweetText image:tweetImage videoURL:nil];
        [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
    }];
  }
```

**TwitterLoggedInInfo** key checking your exist only **read permissions** users, I mean using this key is an optional.